# Suffix on SQL temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, prefix

I am making a script that prints tablenames into a temp table.

I need it to place a suffix to the end like this

```
#temptable1 
#temptable2 
...
#temptableXXX
```

My problem is it doesn't increment when I use rank, and identity doesn't work in a cursor.

I have posted both tries. One of them are commented out.

```
DECLARE @suffix VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE #crs insensitive CURSOR FOR
    SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) AS ID --rank() over (partition by name order by 
name)  --as Identity(1,1) 
    INTO name
    FROM sys.tables
    FOR READ ONLY

OPEN #crs

FETCH NEXT FROM #crs INTO @suffix 

WHLIE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @TabName CURSOR

    SET @TabName = CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT NAME + @suffix
        FROM sys.tables 
        ORDER BY name

    OPEN @TabName 

    PRINT '--- Her skal header printes '

    FETCH NEXT FROM @TabName INTO @TableName 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT @TableName
        ----------------------------------------------------------------- start loop tabel

        ----------------------------------------------------------------- slut loop tabel
        Fetch next from @TabName into @TableName 
    END 

    CLOSE @TabName;  
    DEALLOCATE @TabName;   
END

CLOSE #crs 
DEALLOCATE #crs
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why you need to use a cursor for that? Are you just trying to list all table names like `TableName1, TableName2 ..`?

Comment: I am doing a script that makes delta scripts. To do that I am working with a lot of #temptables, but they need to increment by 1 after each run so I get #temp1, #temp2 etc. Otherwise the compiler says the table already exists

Comment: You still do not need a cursor. But this is also an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask for help on your *y* solution but do not describe the main *x* problem. Building many #temptables can likely be refactored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution to the problem is this.

```
declare @nr int = 0;
set @nr = @nr +1 ;
#TmpTab_'+CONVERT(nvarchar(3), @nr)+'
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are just looking for

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name)) TableName
FROM Sys.Tables;
```

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks alot. It really have been a headache

Comment: Yes, @Maltbeer, please do - that will help others find this answer if they come here with the same problem you had.

Comment: Another solution to the problem is this. 
CONVERT(nvarchar(3), @nr)

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use a cursor :)  I'd do something like this:

```
DECLARE 
    @Table_Name As Varchar(200)
    , @Message As VarChar(Max)
    , @Suffix As Int = 1
    , @Temp_Table_Name As Varchar(100)


Select Distinct 
    name
    , 0 As Processed
Into #Temp_Names
    from sys.tables

While Exists (Select Top 1 1
    FROM #Temp_Names
        WHERE Processed = 0)    
BEGIN
    Select Top 1 
        @Table_Name = name
            From #Temp_Names
            WHERE Processed = 0
    Set @Temp_Table_Name = 'TempTable' + Cast(@Suffix As Varchar(100))

/*

your code here

*/

    Update #Temp_Names
        Set Processed = 1
    Where name = @Table_Name
    Set @Suffix = @Suffix + 1

End
```

You may want to adjust the `Varchar` sizes - I was shooting from the hip.

Comment: How is using a while loop any better than a cursor? In fact, a well tuned cursor can have a slight increase over a while loop. But this doesn't need any looking at all.

Comment: I'm not a performance guru - I just know that when I use this construct rather than the equivalent cursor, this beats a cursor's pants off every time.  I'm talking "order of magnitude" difference.

Comment: Replacing a cursor for a while loop or vice versa is like replacing a vega for a yugo to take to a formula one race. Want to talk "order of magnitude" difference...use set based logic.

Comment: I don't disagree, @SeanLange.  I just know what I've seen, and I'd call 15 minutes to 25 seconds "an order of magnitude".

Comment: If you have that much difference between a while loop and a cursor there is something very wrong. They are usually pretty close with cursors almost always taking the edge. But whatever, a loop if probably not the best construct here since we can easily do some set based logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT NAME+CAST(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NAME) AS VARCHAR) AS NEW_NAME 
FROM SYS.TABLES
```